# [Jmeter]-> Less Than or Greater Than assertion in Jmeter Assertion on API response field

Tags: jmeter

I have an API that responds to a parameter in JSON response body:

```
  {
   "metadata":
      {
        "count": 12206883,
        "pagesize": 100,
        "page": 1,
        "total_pages": 122069,
        "query_time": "1129ms"
  }
}
```

I need to put an assertion in the "query_time" field value that it should be:

<= 1000 ms

I added JSON assertion in JMeter, but it is failing with the below message:

:Value expected to match regexp '<=1000', but it did not match: '102'

Can someone tell me how we can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using [JSON JMESPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Assertion)

Example JSON:

```
{
  "some_attribute": [
    {
      "query_time": 112
    }
  ]
}
```

Example assertion configuration:

[image]

Textual representation just in case:

```
length(some_attribute[?query_time<=`1000`])
```

More information:

- [JMESPath Functions](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#functions)
- [JMESPath Examples](https://jmespath.org/examples.html)
- [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: What is 1 in expected value?

Comment: I used the same which you mentioned above: length(metadata[?query_time<=`1000`]) and it failed with the message: Assertion failure message:Invalid argument type calling "length": expected string, array or object but was null

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Would like to share so that it will help others:

1. Extract the value with the help of JSON Extractor.
   For example:

   ```
   Create variable: querytime
   JSON Path expression: $.metadata.query_time
   ```
2. Now in JSR223 Assertion, write a script: Language: Groovy

   ```
   String jsonString =  vars.get("querytime");
   int length1=jsonString.length();
   String Qtime1=jsonString.substring(0,(length1-2));
   int time = Qtime1.toInteger()
   log.info ("The querytime is " + time); 

   if (time>1000) 
     {
      AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("The Querytime is taking more than 1000ms");
      AssertionResult.setFailure(true); 
     }
   ```